# Battery charging issue in Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, charging

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 and it is charging very very slowly when plugged into my PC. I deleted all my images and some videos and some other stuff and the charging seemed to speed up.

Is battery charging is related to available memory? I didn't think it was.

Comment: Do you use your pc to charge?

Comment: @davidbaumann yup

Comment: It delivers only about 2.5 Watt which might be all used for standby, cell and wifi connection. You should use the charger.

Comment: Did you also delete applications?

Comment: @davidbaumann No. I deleted my Images and some videos... and then i show battery charging speed up little bit.

Comment: Why do you think the charging speed increased? Is it because it became full faster?

Comment: @geffchang i was not thinking. but it's true. when i deleted some images and some other stuff then charging speed little bit increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that `Media Scanner` was scanning a lot of files. Hence, eating up CPU resources and battery. Now that you have lesser files, it's probably not working as hard. See if you have `Media` or `android.process.media` in `System > Battery`.

A rogue app or a corrupted file could be causing `Media` to work hard.

You could also try to clear the phone's cache to see if that helps. Boot into recovery mode, and clear cache partition.

Comment: i think you're right.

Answer (score 2):

This is the due to the change in the supply current between the PC's USB port and the actual plugin charger you got with your device.

Current from USB port is less compared to that of the charger.

Hence time required to charge phone from PC usb port is more as that of charger

Comment: @Santoash ya got it. but when i deleted my images and some other stuff then charging speed little bit increase.

Comment: @MD the best way to compare the charging time is to put your phone in airplane mode and check.\n If results are same then there is some power hungry app that is killing your battery

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the battery's problem, you should get a new battery. I bought one from RAVPower and problem solevd.